# Enpoint protection: How to search an organisation for hash value

Tags: hash, end-points, ioc

As part of incident response to malicious code outbreak and given the hash value of the malicious artifact, I would like to search across the entire organization for this specific hash value.

Do you know of best practices or solutions that implement such functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can scale it, searching across a fleet with Yara rules is better than searching for a hash by a lot

Velociraptor is an open-source implementation of the even rougher standard, RE&CT, which has a response labelled [find process by executable content pattern](https://atc-project.github.io/atc-react/Response_Actions/RA_2406_find_process_by_executable_content_pattern/)

[VQL](https://www.velocidex.com/docs/vql_reference/) (from Velociraptor) is the rough standard for a query language developed for this purpose. Vendors may have their own version of this, but VQL sets the standard for what can and must be done

For Yara, VQL provides the `Windows.Detection.RemoteYara.Process` and `Windows.Detection.ProcessMemory` routines

There are also RE&CTs (e.g., [RA1404](https://atc-project.github.io/atc-react/Response_Actions/RA_1404_get_ability_to_find_process_by_executable_hash/)) and VQL [routines](https://www.velocidex.com/docs/artifacts/misc/#genericutilsfetchbinary) associated with searching by a specific hash, but to reiterate -- levering Yara is better in a majority of use cases

Comment: Windows.Search.Yara for large yara rules and Windows.Search.FileFinder for smaller. https://github.com/Velocidex/yara-tools -- to help minimize yara rules

Answer (score 0):

You get one of the many endpoint agents out there or Powershell scripts that allow you to search for IoCs in the form of file hashes. You tell the agents (or central script) to look for the file hash.